# No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine)

Tags: gruntjs, karma-jasmine

When I run the command `grunt` I get the following warning:

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
Warning: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine) Use --force to continue.
```

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

I had the same error after creating a new project the yeoman angular generator (yo angular).

The solution for me was adding "karma-jasmine" to the devDependencies in packages.json and running "npm install" again.

`npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev`

This solved the error message "No provider for “framework:jasmine”!"

I also had to add a karma browser launcher to the devDependencies, as I got the message that no launcher was installed (see http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/browsers.html).

`npm install karma-safari-launcher --save-dev`

My packages.json looked like this after my action:

```
{
  "name": "test1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-bower-install": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-newer": "~0.5.4",
    "grunt-ngmin": "~0.0.2",
    "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "~2.0.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "~0.1.3",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2.0",
    "time-grunt": "~0.2.1",
    "karma-ng-scenario": "^0.1.0",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.8.0",
    "karma": "^0.12.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.2.2",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "~0.1.1",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
}
```

I changed the following line in karma.conf en karma-e2e.conf to use the karma-safari-launcher:

```
browsers: ['Safari'],
```

I hope this will work for you, too.

Comment: Thanks! The only thing I did different was that I used chrome `npm install karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev`

Comment: @KyleHayes Here is the bug report in the generator-angular project: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/629

Comment: I got `Error: No provider for "framework:karma-chrome-launcher"!` after this

Comment: If you have plugins: [...] added to karma.config.js, then installing karma-jasmine will not solve the issue. you have to add 'karma-jasmine' to plugins array like plugins: ['karma-jasmine'].

Comment: As per my understanding "npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev" was not having any effect on package.json. So Thanks for this solution.

Answer (score 37):

As @Taco said, the default solution for this problem is installing the appropriate plugin, like this: `npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev` or this: `npm install karma-mocha --save-dev`.

However, this error is also expected when you are running an old version of `karma-cli` because they updated the way karma loads the plugins. To make sure you have the latest version, run this:

```
npm install -g karma-cli
```

Comment: This fixed it for me.  I had the dependencies previously mentioned, but karma-cli was out-of-date, apparently.

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thanks buddy

Comment: I ran into this too. Evidently, `npm install -g karma` is *not* the same thing as `npm install -g karma-cli`.

Comment: @PeterMajeed After installing Jasmine, I thought maybe I could `npm install -g karma` but this does NOT work. You must use `npm install -g karma-cli`

Answer (score 34):

My problem was in my `karma.config.js` file:

```
plugins: [require("karma-webpack")]
```

This caused the other `karma-*` plugins not to be loaded, which includes `karma-jasmine`.

Comment: aleclarson's was also my problem.  Since `karma-webpack` was already in my `package.json`'s `devDependencies`, I commented out this `plugins` entry in my `karma.config.js` file.

Answer (score 32):

If your `karma.conf.js` specifies a `plugins` attribute, be sure to add `karma-jasmine` to the list. If all the plugins are prefixed with `karma-`, you don't need to specify this attribute as the plugins will be automatically loaded.

Comment: Thanks, this resolved my issue, adding  karma-jasmine to the plugins!

Comment: Thanks this worked - this is the full line.


```plugins: ['karma-jasmine', 'karma-chrome-launcher', 'karma-spec-reporter', 'karma-coverage'],```

Answer (score 6):

It happened to me because I had Karma installed globally, and when I ran karma start command it actually ran in /usr/... rather than my dev directory.

In my case the solution was to remove karma and install karma-cli instead.

```
npm remove -g karma
npm install -g karma-cli
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem was the selected "Karma package" in the IntelliJ run configuration. I did not select the project's karma package in the project's "node_module" folder:
[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was (missing) looking for.