# configuration of karma/jasmine to test angularjs throws: No provider for "framework:jasmine"!

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Hello I'm trying to implement unit-tests for angularjs with karma and jasmine. I followed therefore this tutorial:
http://tech.pro/tutorial/1473/getting-started-with-angularjs-unit-testing

On the point `Running Your First` Test I get sucked because of an error:

No provider for "framework:jasmine"!

I googled for it and tried the suggested things like installing karma-jasmine and karma-chrome-launcher again but none of these worked for me.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "projectName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a description",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-sass": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "karma": "^0.12.36",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.12",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "^0.1.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "org.apache.cordova.device",
    "org.apache.cordova.console",
    "com.ionic.keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "android",
    "ios"
  ]
}
```

And my karma configuration karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'test/*/Specs.js',
      'test/*'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'Safari'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

If I run `karma start karma.conf.js` I always get the error. I even changed the permission of these two files without any effect. What is the problem here?

Comment: may be that helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367059/no-provider-for-frameworkjasmine-resolving-frameworkjasmine

Comment: I found this post, too but it didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I have installed karma globally `npm install -g karma` and karma-jasmine locally `npm install karma-jasmine`. I reinstalled karma-jasmine globally and now its working.